# Drawing rectangles over a rotated image

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to do ocr on a text which is rotated 90 deg. So to read the text correctly I draw an ROI around it and rotate it to make it straight, like so:

```cs
foundimg = foundimg.Rotate(90), new Gray(255), false);
```

Then do ocr, and draw the bounding rectangles.
But im unable to draw the rectangles on the original image at the correct location.

When i draw it using this code:

```cs
foreach (Rectangle drawrect in charrect)
{
    CvInvoke.Rectangle(resultimg, drawrect, new MCvScalar(0, 252, 0), 1, LineType.EightConnected, 0);
}
```

I get this output:

[image]

When I try to rotate the rectangles using this code:

```cs
foreach (Rectangle drawrect in charrect)
{

    int rotatedX = drawrect.Y + aroi.X;  // Swap X and Y
    int rotatedY = foundimg.Width - drawrect.X - drawrect.Width;  

    int rotatedWidth = drawrect.Height; 
    int rotatedHeight = drawrect.Width;  

    Rectangle rotatedRect = new Rectangle(rotatedX, -rotatedY, rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);

    CvInvoke.Rectangle(resultimg, rotatedRect, new MCvScalar(0, 252, 0), 1, LineType.EightConnected, 0);
}
```

I get this output

[image]

I just cant seem to be able to get the rectangles drawn corectly.
Please help.

Comment: Draw the rectangle on the rotated image and rotate the whole image back.

Comment: Im actually cropping the image using an ROI and using that for OCR. But I found the solution. Mentioning the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to add the cropping roi Y coordinate to Y after swapping to rotate:

```cs
foreach (Rectangle drawrect in temprect)
{
    // Adjust the coordinates based on the rotation
    int rotatedX = drawrect.Y + aroi.X;  // Swap X and Y
    int rotatedY = drawrect.X + aroi.Y;  // Swap X and Y, no need to adjust for the rotation

    int rotatedWidth = drawrect.Height;  // Swap Width and Height
    int rotatedHeight = drawrect.Width;  // Swap Width and Height

    Rectangle rotatedRect = new Rectangle(rotatedX, rotatedY, rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);

    CvInvoke.Rectangle(rimg, rotatedRect, new MCvScalar(0, 252, 0), 1, LineType.EightConnected, 0);
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer by ticking the check mark to the left to close your question.